# How to return set of values from one table and the correct unique value from another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I have been spending the last couple of days trying to figure out this problem.

I have these 2 tables:

(Sorry,  I'm not sure how to indent or tab the tables properly)

```
**Table:**
StaffNo Name    DeptNo
DAX001  Joe     DA001
DAX002  Eric    DA001
DAX003  James   DA002
DAX004  Sarah   DA002
DAX005  Simon   DA003
DAX006  Liam    DA003
DAX007  Denis   DA004
DAX008  Lisa    DA004
DAX009  Eoin    DA005
DAX010  Niall   DA005
DAX011  Richard DA006
DAX012  Steven  DA006

**Department**
DeptNo  DeptName
DA001   Security
DA002   Hospitality
DA003   Check-in
DA004   Airport Assistant
DA005   Airport Police
DA006   Maintenance
```

I am trying to figure out a query that will result with this output.

```
**Output**
Name     DeptName
Joe      Security
Eric     Security
James    Hospitality
Sarah    Hospitality
Simon    Check-in
Liam     Check-in
Denis    Airport Assistant
Lisa     Airport Assistant
Eoin     Airport Police
Niall    Airport Police
Richard  Maintenance
Steven   Maintenance
```

I have made DeptNo from the Department table a Primary key and unique.
I have made DeptNo from the Staff Table a foreign key by referencing DeptNo 
from the Department Table.

Among other attempts, I have tried the following and none of them worked.

Attempt 1.

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff, Department
WHERE Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

Attempt 2.

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff JOIN Department
WHERE Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

Attempt 3.

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff LEFT OUTER JOIN Department 
WHERE Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

Attempt 4.

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff RIGHT OUTER JOIN Department 
WHERE Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

When I tried using...

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff, Department 
WHERE Department.DeptNo = "DAA002"
AND Staff.DeptNo = "DAA002";
```

..I get a list of all the staff with hospitality beside them rather than a list of the 2 names that should have "Hospitality" beside them.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I have tried all your suggestions before and after removing the foreign key.

Before removing the foreign key, I was getting for the most part:

**Output**
Name     DeptName
Joe      Security
Eric     Security
James    Security
Sarah    Security
Simon    Security
Liam     Security
Denis    Security
Lisa     Security
Eoin     Security
Niall    Security
Richard  Security
Steven   Security

After removing foreign key,  I am now getting:

Joe      Security
Joe  Hospitality
Joe  Check-in
Joe  Airport Assistant
Joe  Airport Police
Joe  Maintenance
Eric     Security
Eric     Hospitality
Eric     Check-in
Eric     Airport Assistant
Eric     Airport Police
Eric     Maintenance
James    Security
James    Hospitality
James    Check-in
James    Airport Assistant
James    Airport Police
James    Maintenance
Sarah    Security
Sarah    Hospitality
Sarah    Check-in
Sarah    Airport Assistant
Sarah    Airport Police
Sarah    Maintenance
Simon    Security
Simon    Hospitality
Simon    Check-in
Simon    Airport Assistant
Simon    Airport Police
Simon    Maintenance
Liam     Security
Liam     Hospitality
Liam     Check-in
Liam     Airport Assistant
Liam     Airport Police
Liam     Maintenance
Denis    Security
Denis    Hospitality
Denis    Check-in
Denis    Airport Assistant
Denis    Airport Police
Denis    Maintenance
Lisa     Security
Lisa     Hospitality
Lisa     Check-in
Lisa     Airport Assistant
Lisa     Airport Police
Lisa     Maintenance
Eoin     Security
Eoin     Hospitality
Eoin     Check-in
Eoin     Airport Assistant
Eoin     Airport Police
Eoin     Maintenance
Niall    Security
Niall    Hospitality
Niall    Check-in
Niall    Airport Assistant
Niall    Airport Police
Niall    Maintenance
Richard  Security
Richard  Hospitality
Richard  Check-in
Richard  Airport Assistant
Richard  Airport Police
Richard  Maintenance
Steven   Security
Steven   Hospitality
Steven   Check-in
Steven   Airport Assistant
Steven   Airport Police
Steven   Maintenance

Cheers for the help so far.

Comment: Why would you remove the foreign key? That should not change your query anyway, as it is more of a data integrity constraint. If you are performing a join like I gave in my answer (as well as others gave), then you should not be getting the output that you are. It looks like you are just running a full outer join: `SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName FROM Staff, Department` It looks like you had the query right and somehow changed it...is that what you meant by removing the FK? Please post your current query at least

Answer (score 0):

Attempt 1 should work. However, I would change it to be a more explicit join like you tried in Attempt 2 (the joining clause does not go in the where, but instead in an `ON`)

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff
    JOIN Department
       ON Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

As you said you are new, it might be beneficial to [review this blog post visually showing how joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Also, a google search of SQL JOIN pulls up quite a wealth of knowledge on this subject :)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  Have updated the problem with what I'm getting when I run the queries mentioned in the answers. I still cannot figure out why I am getting this output.  Thanks for the link there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff INNER JOIN Department 
ON Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

Or you can use Distinct keyword if repeated outputs

```
SELECT DISTINCT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff INNER JOIN Department 
ON Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

Comment: Cheers for answering.  Updated the problem above with the output I'm getting in.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt #2 was close.

```
SELECT s.Name, d.DeptName 
FROM Staff s
INNER JOIN Department d
  ON d.DeptNo = s.DeptNo
```

or

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff
INNER JOIN Department
  ON Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo
```

If this doesn't work, could you provide what you are getting as output?

Comment: I have verified this by created your tables, loading the data into the tables and executing the above queries.  Both will yield the output that you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your Foreign keys - you got a Cartesian product in last query.
Try this query:

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Department.DeptName 
FROM Staff JOIN Department
ON Department.DeptNo = Staff.DeptNo;
```

this should got correct answer

Comment: I removed the foreign key from DeptNo in the staff table.  Updated above with the output of the queries.